# getting type error when inserting parameterized query with vbscript in classic asp

Tags: sql, asp-classic, vbscript, parameterized-query

***edit*** still recieving type mismatch error but updated code with help from comments
-updated code shown below

I am new to ASP and VBScript. I am trying to insert post data into a SQL database, however, I want to ensure the query is sterilized so I am trying to use a parameterized query. When I execute the query I get this error.

```
Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a000d'

Type mismatch
```

my code looks like this

```
Set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Mode = 3
conn.open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,xxxx;
database=db_example;uid=user;pwd=password;"

Dim oCmd 
set oCmd= Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command") 

Dim sSQL 
sSQL = "INSERT INTO tbl_Application (Expenses, Name, Why) VALUES (?, ?, ?);"
oCmd.CommandText = sSQL
oCmd.ActiveConnection= conn

Dim uPar 
uPar = oCmd.CreateParameter("Expenses",200,1,255,session("Expenses")) 
oCmd.Parameters.Append(uPar)

Dim vPar 
vPar = oCmd.CreateParameter("Name",200,1,255,session("Name")) 
oCmd.Parameters.Append(vPar)

Dim wPar 
wPar = oCmd.CreateParameter("Why",200,1,255,session("Why")) 
oCmd.Parameters.Append(wPar)

Dim oRS 
oRS = oCmd.Execute()
```

I have tried typing the data as a varchar and a char. Please let me know if you have a fix for my problem. Also, I am intending to insert more than three pieces of data on the site - is there a better way than going through and making a parameter manually for each column?

Comment: you have to use `Dim` for declaring variables using vbscript. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t7zd6etz%28v=vs.84%29.aspx. `var` is used in jscript

Comment: thanks, switched to dim, however, wouldn't let me define the Dim on declaration. Aka I have to write `Dim xyz` and then on second line `xyz = "something"`

Comment: yes, you have to do it in a new line; or you can do: `Dim xyz : xyz = "something"`

Comment: check this for the `createparameter` method, notice the use of `set` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675860%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: What line throw that error?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for the [`CreateParameter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677209%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method state that:

> If you specify a variable-length data type in the *Type* argument, you
>   must either pass a *Size* argument or set the Size property of the
>   **Parameter** object before appending it to the **Parameters** collection;
>   otherwise, an error occurs.

`129` corresponds to `adChar`, which is a variable-length data type and therefore requires you to pass a `Size` argument. Usually, you should use the defined length of the column in the database, but I have found that just using the length of the value I'm passing works also.

Comment: Mmmm good to know, however, after adding in size property still throwing the type mismatch error - Provider error '80020005'. Any other ideas. Changed parameter code to this                           `Dim uPar 
    uPar = oCmd.CreateParameter("Expenses",200,1,255,session("Expenses")) 
    oCmd.Parameters.Append(uPar)`